# How to animate ffmpeg's boxblur

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am running the following ffmpeg command which converts a single image to a 10 second slow-zoom into the center of the photo.

As you can see, I currently have the `boxblur`looking how I would like it, but it is applied to the entire 10 second clip. I'd like to blur the first 3 seconds, and then animate the radius of the blur from it's current value of `boxblur=10:9` to `boxblur=0:0` from 3.0 - 4.0 seconds (24 frames at 24p).

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i image.jpg -vf "boxblur=10:9,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240:s=hd1080:fps=24" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 -s hd1080 -crf 20  video.mp4
```

Any help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240:s=hd1080:fps=24,split[base][blur];[blur]trim=duration=4,boxblur=10:9,format=yuva420p,fade=out:st=3:d=1:alpha=1[blurred];[base][blurred]overlay" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 -crf 20  video.mp4
```

The boxblur options don't support time-based animation, so the way to get this done is to perform the zoompan, then split that result. In one of the child streams, the boxblur is applied for the first 4 seconds. The trim isn't necessary but will quicken the execution somewhat. Then the pixel format of that stream has an alpha channel added, which is completely opaque. A fade-out is applied to only the alpha channel from 3 to 4 seconds. Then that result is overlaid upon the other child stream. When a stream with alpha is overlaid over another stream, the alpha value determines the opacity of the top layer. Since the alpha is faded out from 3 to 4 seconds, the top layer 'crossfades' to the base layer. This, in effect, reduces the boxblur to 0.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the error: `Unable to parse option value "min(36 - 9*t, 9)` out of ffmpeg's server response?

Comment: Looks like boxblur can't be animated in time. I'll provide a replacement command.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated. I'll test this soon, but in the meantime, I'll look forward to your comments regarding how this works.